# Indy 10. How to send multiple commands at once?

Tags: delphi, indy

Tell me that I have ideology is not correct in this code.

One command I send and get an answer without any problems. But if I want (more precisely, it is necessary to send it by task) N commands and receive correctly all the answers.

How to correctly send one by one command, waiting until the previous one is fully completed.

Sending several commands, losing the connection, but sometimes skips, change CheckForDataOnSource (100); - Does not help.

Today I have about the following code:

```
ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyServ: TMyServer;
begin
  ...
  MyServ.SendCommand('command 1');
  ...
  MyServ.SendCommand('command N');
end;
```

```
unit MyServer;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, IdContext, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, Vcl.StdCtrls, IdGlobal,
  XMLDoc, XMLDOM, XMLIntf, ActiveX, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls, Base64, IdSync, IdCmdTCPServer,
  IdYarn, IdTCPConnection, IdThreadSafe;

type
  TMyServer = class(TIdTCPServer)
  private
    FEndResponse: string;
    FTotalStr: string;
    procedure Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
    //procedure ParseRecv(RecvText: string);
  public
    procedure Run(BindIP: string; BindPort: Integer);
    procedure Stop;
    procedure SendCommand(Cmd: string);
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TMySync = class(TIdSync)
  protected
    procedure DoSynchronize; override;
  public
    Data: string;
    Server: TMyServer;
  end;

  TMyContext = class(TIdServerContext)
  public
    Queue: TIdThreadSafeStringList;
    constructor Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  FReady: Boolean = True;

implementation

uses Main;

procedure TMySync.DoSynchronize;
begin
  //Server.ParseRecv(Data);
  MainForm.Memo1.Lines.Add(Data);
end;

constructor TMyServer.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ContextClass := TMyContext;
  OnExecute := Execute;
  FEndResponse := '</response>';
end;

destructor TMyServer.Destroy;
begin
  Stop;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

constructor TMyContext.Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil);
begin
  inherited Create(AConnection, AYarn, AList);
  Queue := TIdThreadSafeStringList.Create;
end;

destructor TMyContext.Destroy;
begin
  Queue.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;


procedure TMyServer.Run(BindIP: string; BindPort: Integer);
begin
  DefaultPort := 0;
  Bindings.Clear;
  with Bindings.Add do begin
    IP := BindIP;
    Port := BindPort;
  end;
  Active := True;
end;

procedure TMyServer.Stop;
begin
  Active := False;
end;

procedure TMyServer.SendCommand(Cmd: string);
var
  List: TList;
  Ctx: TMyContext;
begin
  List := Contexts.LockList;
  try
    //Connection Server <-> Client once one to one
    Ctx := TMyContext(List[0]);
    Ctx.Queue.Add(Cmd);
  finally
    Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyServer.Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Buffer: TIdBytes;
  Size, RecvSizeLen: Integer;
  RecvStr: string;
  Sync: TMySync;
  Ctx: TMyContext;
  Queue: TStringList;
begin
  Buffer := nil;

  with AContext.Connection.IOHandler do begin
    CheckForDataOnSource(100);
    if not InputBufferIsEmpty then begin
      Size := StrToInt(ReadLn());
      InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(Buffer);
      SetString(RecvStr, PAnsiChar(@Buffer[0]), Size);

      FTotalStr := FTotalStr + RecvStr;
      if ((Copy(FTotalStr, Length(FTotalStr) - Length(FEndResponse), Length(FEndResponse))) = FEndResponse)
      then begin
        if Length(FTotalStr) > 0 then begin
          Sync := TMySync.Create;
          try
            Sync.Server := Self;
            Sync.Data := FTotalStr;
            Sync.Synchronize;
          finally
            Sync.Free;
          end;
        end;
        FTotalStr := '';
      end;
    end else begin
      Ctx := TMyContext(AContext);
      Queue := Ctx.Queue.Lock;
      //????????????????????????????????
      while (Queue.Count > 0) do begin
        try
          Ctx.Connection.IOHandler.Write(Queue[0] + #0);
          Queue.Delete(0);
        finally
          Ctx.Queue.Unlock;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a number of problems with your `Execute` code.

- when reading a reply, you first read a size from the connection, but then you ignore that size when calling `ExtractToBytes()` so it ends up returning all available bytes, and then you use the size to copy a portion of the extracted bytes into a string and throw away the rest of the bytes. So this logic is potentially throwing away bytes from your protocol and corrupting your communications. You should not be using `ExtractToBytes()` like this at all, use the IOHandler's `ReadBytes()` method instead, or maybe `ReadString()`, depending on the  version of Delphi you are using and the nature of the strings you are reading.
- when checking the Queue for data to send, you lock the queue but then do not unlock it if it is empty. And if it is not empty, you unlock at the end of each loop iteration without re-locking it first. Your `try..finally` needs to be moved outside of the `while` loop.

Try this instead:

```
// if you are using D2009+, add this...
uses
 ..., System.AnsiStrings;

procedure TMyServer.Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  IO: TIdIOHandler;
  Buffer: TIdBytes;
  Size: Integer;
  RecvStr: AnsiString;
  Sync: TMySync;
  Ctx: TMyContext;
  Queue: TStringList;
begin
  IO := AContext.Connection.IOHandler;
  if IO.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    IO.CheckForDataOnSource(100);
    IO.CheckForDisconnect;
  end;
  if not IO.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    Size := StrToInt(IO.ReadLn());

    // if using D2007 or earlier...
    RecvStr := IO.ReadString(Size);

    // if using D2009 or later...
    IO.ReadBytes(Buffer, Size, False);
    SetString(RecvStr, PAnsiChar(Pointer(Buffer)), Size);

    FTotalStr := FTotalStr + RecvStr;
    if AnsiEndsStr(FEndResponse, FTotalStr) then
    begin
      Sync := TMySync.Create;
      try
        Sync.Server := Self;
        Sync.Data := FTotalStr;
        Sync.Synchronize;
      finally
        Sync.Free;
      end;
      FTotalStr := '';
    end;
  end else
  begin
    Ctx := TMyContext(AContext);
    Queue := Ctx.Queue.Lock;
    try
      while (Queue.Count > 0) do
      begin
        IO.Write(Queue[0] + #0);
        Queue.Delete(0);
      end;
    finally
      Ctx.Queue.Unlock;
    end;
  end;
end;
```